# How can I limit user input length on python?

Tags: python

```
amt = float(input("Please enter the amount to make change for: $"))
```

I'd like the user to enter an amount in dollars and therefore allow 5 characters (00.00) Is there a way to limit it so it wont allow them to enter more than 5 characters?

I don't want something like this where it allows you to input more than 5 but will loop.

```
while True:
amt = input("Please enter the amount to make change for: $")
if len(amt) <= 5:
        print("$" + amt)
        break
```

I want complete restriction from entering more than 5 characters

Comment: what do you want to happen if the user enters more than 5 characters?

Comment: Tip: Use a regex pattern to validate input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

Comment: you could ignore the other chars with `input(...)[:5]`

Comment: @Phydeaux I want it not to allow to enter more than 5. like imaging holding down a key and it stops at 5

Comment: Have a look at argparse

Comment: @Cherry you cannot do this simply, or with `input` - see the question in @CharlieWindolf's comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use **curses**

there is other approaches but i think this is a simple one.

[read about curses module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#module-curses)

you can use **getkey()** or **getstr()**. but using getstr() is simpler, and it give the user choice to enter less than 5 char if he want, but no more than 5. i think that is what you asked for.

```
 import curses
 stdscr = curses.initscr()
 amt = stdscr.getstr(1,0, 5) # third arg here is the max length of allowed input
```

but if you want to force 5 character , no less , no more, you may want to use getkey() and put it in for loop , in this example program will wait user to enter 5 character before continue , no need even to press return key.

```
amt = ''
stdscr = curses.initscr() 
for i in range(5): 
     amt += stdscr.getkey() # getkey() accept only one char, so we put it in a for loop
```

**note:**

you need to call the endwin() function to restore the terminal to its original operating mode.

> A common problem when debugging a curses application is to get your
>   terminal messed up when the application dies without restoring the
>   terminal to its previous state. In Python this commonly happens when
>   your code is buggy and raises an uncaught exception. Keys are no
>   longer echoed to the screen when you type them, for example, which
>   makes using the shell difficult.

**putting all together:**

going with first example, implementing getstr() method in your program could be like this:

```
import curses 

def input_amount(message): 
    try: 
        stdscr = curses.initscr() 
        stdscr.clear() 
        stdscr.addstr(message) 
        amt = stdscr.getstr(1,0, 5) # or use getkey() as showed above.
    except: 
        raise 
    finally: 
        curses.endwin() # to restore the terminal to its original operating mode.
    return amt


amount = input_amount('Please enter the amount to make change for: $') 
print("$" + amount.decode())
```