# Limiting Python input to a certain length

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and programming so I just wanted to know how to restrict the user input to a certain length.
For example, if the length of a credit card number is 16 digits and I wanted to restrict the length of the input to 16, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: It has been already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952296/how-can-i-limit-user-input-length-on-python

Comment: After they enter the number, check if the length is longer than 16. If it is, loop back and ask again.