# Stopping user from inputting more than desired characters

Tags: python, input, terminal

In python I want to have an input where a user enters plaintext and if whatever they enter is more than 16 characters, then only the first 16 characteres are shown and not the rest. For example, if they type 'ilovethisclass!!sosomuch' on their keyboard, then it only shows 'ilovethisclass!!' in the terminal and the rest nothing happens. Whatever they enter in their keyboard that is more than 16 characters, the terminal doesnt allow them to type more.

I tried going on chatGPT to see how to do this but cant get anything to work, also tried this but did not work:

```
plaintext = plaintext[:16]
```

this is what i have:

```
plaintext = input("\nEnter plaintext (16 characters):           ")
```

Comment: your program can emit characters that can directly control the way the terminal is displayed. So you could, for example, read the input and then update the terminal display to have only the characters you want. for instance: https://www.makeuseof.com/python-cli-progress-bar-tqdm/

Comment: As you've found out, it's easy to limit the input to a certain length _after_ you accept it from the user with `plaintext = plaintext[:16]`. Limiting it while the user is typing is [a little harder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952296/how-can-i-limit-user-input-length-on-python). If I were you, I'd just take the easier road and discard the extra characters, then print a message informing the user what's happened (unless you have a really good reason to limit the user's input while they're typing it)